# Xamarin Forms UWP Does Not React to Bindingcontext

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a xamarin forms open source project, the app pulls data from id.wikihow.com.

Github repo : https://github.com/become90/Otodidak

My problem is the app works on Android but not quite works on UWP.

No data displayed on the view on UWP, it just blank.
The view reacts if the data is local.

UPDATE :
On further investigation, i checked if the INotifyPropertyChanged Handler is triggered on UWP, and it's triggered. But somehow the view does not reflect the viewmodel.

[image]

Here is my viewmodel :

```
namespace Otodidak.ViewModels
 {
public class HalamanUtamaViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Post> BodyPosts { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Post> HeaderPosts { get; set; } 

    public Command LoadHeaderCommand { get; set; }
    public Command LoadBodyCommand { get; set; }

    public HalamanUtamaViewModel()
    {
        HeaderPosts = new ObservableRangeCollection<Post>();
        BodyPosts = new ObservableRangeCollection<Post>();

        LoadHeaderCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteHeaderCommand());
        LoadBodyCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteBodyCommand());
    }

    public async Task ExecuteHeaderCommand()
    {
        if (IsHeaderBusy)
            return;

        IsHeaderBusy = true;

        try
        {
            HeaderPosts.Clear();
            await getHeaderArticleData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            MessagingCenter.Send(new MessagingCenterAlert
            {
                Title = "Error",
                Message = "Unable to load items.",
                Cancel = "OK"
            }, "message");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsHeaderBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task ExecuteBodyCommand()
    {
        if (IsBodyBusy)
            return;

        IsBodyBusy = true;

        try
        {
            BodyPosts.Clear();
            await getBodyArticleData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            MessagingCenter.Send(new MessagingCenterAlert
            {
                Title = "Error",
                Message = "Unable to load items.",
                Cancel = "OK"
            }, "message");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBodyBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task getHeaderArticle()
    {
        await getHeaderArticleData();

    }

    public async Task getHeaderArticleData()
    {

        if (HeaderPosts.Count != 0)
            return;

        string htmlPage;

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://id.wikihow.com/Halaman-Utama").ConfigureAwait(false);
            }


            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
            var innerText = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("div")
                .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "hp_top").ToList();


            foreach (var div in innerText)
            {
                Post newPosts = new Post();
                string imageUrl = "";
                string title = "";
                string url = "";

                string htmlDiv = "<html>" + div.OuterHtml + "</html>";



                imageUrl = Regex.Match(htmlDiv, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
                title = Regex.Match(htmlDiv, "<div.+?title=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
                url = Regex.Match(htmlDiv, "<a.+?href=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
                title = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(title);
                //HtmlDecode
                //"http://id.wikihow.com" +
                newPosts.Title ="CARA "+ title;
                newPosts.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
                newPosts.PostUrl = "http://id.wikihow.com" + url;

                HeaderPosts.Add(newPosts);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }

    public async Task getBodyArticle()
    {
        await getBodyArticleData();
    }

    public async Task getBodyArticleData()
    {
        if (BodyPosts.Count != 0)
            return;

        string htmlPage;

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://id.wikihow.com/Halaman-Utama").ConfigureAwait(false);
            }


            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
            var innerText = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("div")
                .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("id", "") == "fa_container").FirstOrDefault();

            innerHtmlDocument.LoadHtml(innerText.OuterHtml);

            var td = innerHtmlDocument.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("td").ToList();

            PostHelper ph = new PostHelper();
            var bodyposts = ph.GetPostFromTd(td);
            BodyPosts.ReplaceRange(bodyposts);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }


    }
}

 }
```

Here is how i consume it

```
 namespace Otodidak.Views
 {
public partial class HeaderPage : ContentPage
{
    HalamanUtamaViewModel vm;

    public HeaderPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm = new HalamanUtamaViewModel();
        //BindingContext = vm = new HalamanUtamaViewModel();
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.SelectedItem as Post;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item))));

        // Manually deselect item
        HeaderListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();
        if (vm.HeaderPosts.Count == 0)
            vm.LoadHeaderCommand.Execute(null);


    }
}
 }
```

And this is the xaml page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Otodidak.Views.HeaderPage"
         Title="Halaman Utama">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="HeaderListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding HeaderPosts}"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadHeaderCommand}"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsHeaderBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start"
                                         Padding="20"
                                         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
                                <Label TextColor="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource UpperCaseHelper}}"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                       LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                            <OnPlatform.iOS>MarkerFelt-Thin</OnPlatform.iOS>
                                            <OnPlatform.Android>Droid Sans Mono</OnPlatform.Android>
                                            <OnPlatform.WinPhone>"Comic Sans MS</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you specify your exact issue?

Comment: No data displayed on the view on UWP, it just blank.
The view reacts if the data is local.

Comment: To reproduce need the follow code: BaseViewModel
ObservableRangeCollection
Post
IsHeaderBusy
MessagingCenterAlert
IsBodyBusy
HeaderPosts
PostHelper
htmlDocument not defined

Comment: Please feel free to access the git repro here : https://github.com/become90/Otodidak

Comment: NEVER EVER leave a catch empty. at least log the error.

Comment: Thanks @Dbl, i will put more log at the catch.